# Is there a simple, direct way to set the font directly in a Beamer template?

Tags: beamer, fonts, templates

By combining results from various answers in this community, I've set my navigation symbols as follows to only display page numbers:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
  \usebeamercolor[darkgray]{}
  \setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
  \usebeamerfont{footline}
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

This works perfectly well, but I'm a bit mystified by the convoluted way of setting the font options. Is there a way to combine these three separate lines into one or two? Why can't the font color be "set" like other font attributes can? Why do I need to separately "set" and "use" a new font which I never use again in the document? Is there a single-line command to set the font within a template that (schematically) goes something like `\usebeamerfont{size=9,color=\darkgray}` or something like that?

Comment: You could simply do `\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont` and omit the whole beamer boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the TeXnician already mentioned in his comment, you can always just skip beamer's font mechanism if you don't like it and use

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

The idea behind the beamers font mechanism is to be able to easily adjust for example the font size without redefining the whole template.

Assuming you have the following code in your theme

```
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
  \usebeamercolor{footline}
  \usebeamerfont{footline}
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
```

you can simply change the font or colour by setting them in your presentation without having to redefine the whole `navigation symbols` template.

Another advantage is that these definition can be sorted into `color/font/inner/outer` theme, which makes is very easy to find which `color/font/template` to change.